# C3P0ConnectionProvider error when deploying on JBoss

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, jboss, c3p0

I'm attempting to connect to a MySQL database via JPA on a JBoss server.

I get the following exception when deploying my project.

```
13:04:41,035 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."dryrun.war#dbname": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."dryrun.war#dbname": Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]

Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: dbname] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:73)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
... 3 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:187)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735)
at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
... 9 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:190)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:112)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:177)
... 22 more

Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:187)
... 26 more

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356) [rt.jar:1.7.0_15]
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
... 27 more
```

My persistence.xml file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<persistence-unit name="dbname" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize" value="0" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize" value="25" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge" value="14400" />
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime" value="100" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

My pom.xml file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>projectname</groupId>
<artifactId>projectname</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <version.jboss.bom>1.0.4.Final</version.jboss.bom>
</properties>
<build><!-- Maven will append the version to the finalName (which is the 
        name given to the generated war, and hence the context root) -->
    <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    <plugins><!-- Compiler plugin enforces Java 1.6 compatibility and activates 
            annotation processors -->
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration><!-- Java EE 6 doesn't require web.xml, Maven needs to 
                    catch up! -->
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin><!-- The JBoss AS plugin deploys your war to a local JBoss AS 
            container --><!-- To use, run: mvn package jboss-as:deploy -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1.Final</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.as</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-as-jpa-hibernate3</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-rc1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1-20130222</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.2-pre8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I've tried a number of different c3p0 related dependencies from Hibernate and other ones I could find, but nothing seems to get the project working. Could someone please point me in the right direction. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular dependency that you were missing is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

The class that you were missing used to be in hibernate-core, but it was moved here probably around version 3.3

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0

http://gazelle.ihe.net/content/how-use-c3p0-jdbc-connection-pool-your-maven-project

Answer (score 1):

Well I fixed this issue by just bundling all of the c3p0 dependencies I could find on Maven into the project at the same time. I'm not sure which of the dependencies fixed the issue but one of them did. Therefore it seems this issue was due to a missing jar, which is what I suspected from the ClassNotFoundException.