# hibernate-c3p0 not being seen by hibernate module's classloader

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss, classloader, c3p0

I am having a really strange issue with my spring/hibernate/c3p0/jboss app.  When it starts up, the log shows

> 16:42:09,219 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
>
> 16:42:09,235 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider] (MSC service thread 1-4) HHH010002: C3P0 using driver: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver at URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@...

A little ways down, though, when it attempts to create the SessionFactory bean, I see

> 16:42:11,219 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider

followed by a spectacular stack trace ending with

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">...</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

context:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("...")
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager manager = new HibernateTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
        return manager;
    }
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="primary" transaction-type="JTA">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.ejb.cfgfile" value="hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

```
hibernate version: 4.0.1.Final
spring: 3.2.3.RELEASE
jboss: 7.1.1
c3p0: 0.9.1 (version listed as a dependency of hibernate-c3p0)
```

*EDIT*
Stack Trace:

```
10:16:51,253 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/...]] (MSC service thread 1-7) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scenarioController' defined in "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/.../web/controllers/ScenarioController.class": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [...dao.interfaces.ScenarioDao]: : Error creating bean with name 'scenarioDaoImpl' defined in "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/app.war/WEB-INF/classes/com/.../dao/ScenarioDaoImpl.class": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class app.web.config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory ...web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class ....web.config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory ....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scenarioDaoImpl' defined in "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/....war/WEB-INF/classes/com/.../dao/ScenarioDaoImpl.class": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.....web.config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.....config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'scenarioDaoImpl' defined in "/C:/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/bin/content/....war/WEB-INF/classes/com/.../dao/ScenarioDaoImpl.class": Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory]: : Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.....web.config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.....web.config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:730) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:196) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1045) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:949) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class com.....web.config.PersistenceContext: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:581) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1025) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:921) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:487) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:795) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:723) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
... 37 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:181) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:570) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
... 50 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:187) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:234) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:91) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2270) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2266) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1735) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1775) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:247) [spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:373) [spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:358) [spring-orm-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.....web.config.PersistenceContext.sessionFactory(PersistenceContext.java:23) [classes:]
at com.....web.config.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$407e55e5.CGLIB$sessionFactory$1(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:]
at com.....web.config.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$407e55e5$$FastClassByCGLIB$$22f280c.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) [spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:286) [spring-context-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
at com.....web.config.PersistenceContext$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$407e55e5.sessionFactory(<generated>) [spring-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:160) [spring-beans-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar:3.2.3.RELEASE]
... 51 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:190) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:112) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:177) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
... 77 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:187) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
... 81 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252) [rt.jar:1.6.0_12]
at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138) [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]
... 82 more
```

I can see both hibernate-c3p0-4.0.1.Final.jar and c3p0-0.9.1.jar in the deploy directory, they're definitely being included.  I even opened up hibernate-c3p0-4.0.1.Final.jar to make sure the class is really in there, and it's exactly where it should be.

I've been stepping through this in the debugger.  The first time, the class is successfully being loaded by the ModuleClassLoader for deployment.tdm-web-proof-of-concept.war:main.  The second time, the ModuleClassLoader for org.hibernate:main is trying and failing to find it.  I'm convinced that this is some sort of configuration issue where the hibernate module's classloader can't see this.  Any ideas how I can point it in the right direction?

Comment: did you add all the other jars that hibernate depends on?

Comment: JBoss classloading is modular, so the same class may be visible from one module, and not from other. Please add the *spectacular stacktrace*.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15158783/c3p0connectionprovider-error-when-deploying-on-jboss

Comment: Try with [EAP 6.1](http://www.jboss.org/products/eap).

Comment: EAP 6.1 will not work on this machine.  I'm hoping that this issue can be fixed for AS 7.1.1.  Ondra, I looked at that thread and I don't really think "include all of the things" is the way to go.  The required dependencies are definitely being deployed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in this version of `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory()`.
It incorrectly assumes that the deprecated method in the hibernate class it inherits from will load both the classloader that loaded it and the TCCL, which is an implementation detail.  Instead, this method only uses the classloader that loaded it, the hibernate module's classloader.  This classloader does not have the deployment classes on its classpath, so it's throwing the ClassNotFoundException.

From this, we can safely say that the `org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean` in this version of spring cannot be used with this version of hibernate 4.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-could-not-find-c3p0connectionprovider/ :

It is rather old, I'd say pre-AS 7, but may apply as well.
Of course you have to match the version with the Hibernate included in AS.

---

Since Hibernate v3.3 (if not mistaken), the “C3P0ConnectionProvider” is moved to another jar file “hibernate-c3p0.jar“. You need to include it, in order to make Hibernate supports c3p0 connection pool.

You can download the “hibernate-c3p0.jar” from JBoss public repository.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss repository</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Hibernate c3p0 connection pool -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I've already added this dependency from the central repository.  This is sufficient, right?
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/4.0.1.Final

Comment: Actually I was wrong, I had added that repository a while ago to the profile I'm using